# Can I find list of japanese names in kanji with latin equivalent?

Tags: translation, names

I need such list at size of at least 5000 entries for sowftware performance testing purpose. The best format of list would be a CSV. For example:

```
佐藤琢磨;Kamui Kobayashi
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.edrdg.org/enamdict/enamdict_doc.html has 30500 (`h - full (usually family plus given) name of a particular person`) but it's in XML

Comment: @siikamiika doesn't matter if it's an xml file, I'll manage that, but this is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off-topic.

Comment: 佐藤琢磨; Kamui Kobayashi ---> Takuma Sato

Comment: Latin---> alphabet or the Roman alphabet